# How many five-digit numbers have digit product 6!

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

The product of the digits of a five-digit number is $6!=720$. How many such numbers are there?

Comment: Referring to [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic): it's not entirely clear how this is a math *puzzle* as opposed to a math *problem*.

Comment: This question might benefit from explicitly stating whether the exclamation mark is supposed to represent a factorial, or is merely the sign of a very excited question asker. It has been interpreted both ways in the first 2 answers! (Exclamation mark used here for excited commenting purposes...)

Comment: If the point of the question is deliberate confusion about the factorials, see the evergreen [xkcd 169](https://xkcd.com/169/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 660, according to the Perl 5 one-liner
>  `for(10000..99999){$i++if eval(join'*',split//,$_)==6*5*4*3*2}print$i`

Comment: Note that this assumes "6!" in the question means "the factorial of six". [The answer that immediately followed mine](/a/103989/93) assumes it means "six, wow".

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the ! is a factorial, there are

> $660 = 3 \cdot 5! + 4*\frac {5!}{2!}+2 \cdot \frac{5!}{2!^2}$

because:

> 3 possible sets with unique digits: $\{1,2,5,8,9\},\{1,3,5,6,8\},\{2,3,4,5,6\}$
>  4 possible sets with one digit repeated once: $\{1,4,4,5,9\}, \{1,4,5,6,6\}, \{2,2,4,5,9\}, \{2,3,3,5,8\}$
>  2 possible sets with two repeated digits one time each: $\{2,2,5,6,6\}, \{3,3,4,4,5\}$
>  Then just calculate number of permutations

Process for finding sets:

> All possible sets must contain $5$, because $6!$ can only be divided once by $5$ -> so we only need to make the product of 4 digits equal $144$ now.
>  Iterate through all 1-digit divisors $d$ of $144$, try to make the product of the remaining 3 digits equal $\frac {144} d$, which shouldn't take too long to do by hand, since you should be able to eliminate many options / duplicates and find limits fairly quickly. I'm speaking in this way because I also let a computer find all the 9 sets mentioned above for me, but I wanted to add an explanation of why it is 660 or how you could do it.

Answer (score 2):

There are

> 25

such numbers.

Reasoning:

> First we need to determine the possible numbers that are factors of 6, so that's 1 and 6 or 2 and 3. We then fill in the remaining 3 digits with 1s to get a 5 digit number. There are 5 permutations for 4 1s and 1 6, and 20 permutations for 3 1s, 1 2, and 1 3. This makes a total of 25 permutations.

The total list:

> 1,1,1,1,6 | 1,1,1,6,1 | 1,1,6,1,1 | 1,6,1,1,1 | 6,1,1,1,1
>  1,1,1,2,3 | 1,1,2,1,3 | 1,2,1,1,3 | 2,1,1,1,3
>  1,1,1,3,2 | 1,1,3,1,2 | 1,3,1,1,2 | 3,1,1,1,2
>  1,1,2,3,1 | 1,2,1,3,1 | 2,1,1,3,1
>  1,1,3,2,1 | 1,3,1,2,1 | 3,1,1,2,1
>  1,2,3,1,1 | 2,1,3,1,1 | 1,3,2,1,1 | 3,1,2,1,1
>  2,3,1,1,1 | 3,2,1,1,1

Comment: Ah, I see you interpreted the exclamation mark as merely punctuation rather than a factorial operation! I think the question needs some clarity as which was intended, so I have commented as such on the question itself...

Comment: Note that this answer assumes "6!" in the question means "six, wow". [My earlier answer](/a/103988/93) assumes it means "the factorial of six".

Comment: Ha, yeah, mind didn't even jump to factorial (although in hindsight I think that makes more sense from an "interesting" math perspective (since 6 by itself does make the problem somewhat trivial)

Comment: Grammatically, if a factorial is the end of a sentence should there still be punctuation? I was an English major, math minor, so I think that's why I jumped to punctuation vs. math symbol

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right that if it means factorial it should say "...is 6!." -- but my own mind went straight to factorial without even considering the alternative. I don't know which was intended, of course, but perhaps the OP will chime in.